# Tactics: stuck in eqb_trans

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Trying to solve eqb_trans I became stuck:

```
Theorem eqb_trans : forall n m p,
  n =? m = true ->
  m =? p = true ->
  n =? p = true.
```

Obviously, we should use eqb_true to solve it:

```
Theorem eqb_true : forall n m,
    n =? m = true -> n = m.
--------------------------------------------
Proof.
  intros n m p H1 H2. apply eqb_true in H1.
  apply eqb_true with (n:=m)(m:=p) in H2.
```

At this point we have:

```
n, m, p : nat
H1 : n = m
H2 : m = p
============================
(n =? p) = true
```

Now I wanted to use eqb_true upon the goal:

```
apply eqb_true with (m:=p).
```

But here we get an error:

```
Unable to unify "?M1056 = p" with "(n =? p) = true".
```

Why doesn't it work? How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply a lemma to the goal, it is the *conclusion* of the lemma that must unify with the goal rather than its premise. The conclusion of this lemma is of the form `_ = _`, while your goal is `(_ =? _) = true`.  These two cannot be unified, which leads to the error you see.

To prove `eqb_trans`, you need the converse of `eqb_true`, namely

```
forall n m, n = m -> (n =? m) = true,
```

which, after some simplification, is equivalent to

```
forall n, (n =? n) = true.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Theorem eqb_trans : forall n m p,
    n =? m = true ->
    m =? p = true ->
    n =? p = true.
Proof.
  intros n m p.
  repeat rewrite  Nat.eqb_eq.
  intros.
  rewrite H.
  exact H0.
Qed.
```

-- Check Nat.eqb_eq.

```
Nat.eqb_eq                                                                                          
 : forall n m : nat, (n =? m) = true <-> n = m
```